# List of tuples from a list in pandas dataframe (shapley objects)

Tags: pandas, networkx, arcgis

This is my pandas series which I want to create as a source and destination node for networkx, that is, Point essentially is the latitute and longitude.

```
[POINT (35.2363 166.0467), POINT (35.2364 166.047), POINT (35.2363 166.0473), ......]

pseudocode: dd['geometry'].apply(lambda x : [zip(k,k+1) for k in k])
```

What I want to do is create a tuple of those geometry objects.

For an instance,

```
[(POINT (35.2363 166.0467), POINT (35.2364 166.047)),(POINT (35.2363 166.0467), POINT (35.2363 166.0473)), (POINT (35.2364 166.047), POINT (35.2363 166.0473))]
```

Any thoughtful answer will be helpful. It does not have to be code specific. Pardon my lack of geospatial knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `combinations` from `itertools`. From the [wiki](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

> r-length tuples, in sorted order, no repeated elements

In you example you can do:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> list(itertools.combinations(a, r=2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

Comment: this is all great, but comibinations is super slow. I found a better way to handle shapley objects

Comment: Generally itertools function are very fast. Can you post an example where `itertools.combinations` would be the bottleneck?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is related to shapley object. We probably better off using MGRS library and converting the lat/lon (as in `POINT` object above) and treating this therefrom.

```
import mgrs
m = mgrs.MGRS()
eg :  POINT (35.2363 166.0467), 
lon = 166.0467 
lat =35.2363
m.toMGRS(lat, lon)
```

generates

```
b'58SED9523999750'
```

and obviously this is a node that networkx can interpret.